# Use type from module in namespace augmentation

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, typescript-typings

I am trying to use Typescript type augmentation to extend the test framework, i.e. Mocha's `Context` class, so that I can do:

```js
beforeEach(function() {
    this.myMethod();
});
```

Upstream typings [use a namespace](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0ba1042e325ba18b3b20d5292ed31666ce383ccd/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L1284), so
patching the prototype and adding a .d.ts file like this works:

```js
declare namespace Mocha {
    interface Context {
        myMethod(): string;
    }
}
```

The troubles start when I try to use other types with the augmentation.

My code base is written with modules and let's say I have a module like:

```js
export interface MyType {
//...
}
```

As soon as any import is used in the namespace augmentation, it stops working.

How can I use `MyType` in the signature of `myMethod`?

I figure something like this is not unthinkable and could be used perhaps to retrofit support for Moment to a library that only works with Date, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently going through the `global` namespace does the trick:

```js
import { MyType } from "../src/MyType";

declare global {
    namespace Mocha {
        export interface Context {
            myMethod(): MyType;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solution no longer works. Try this instead:

```
import { YourType } from "../src/YourType";

declare module "mocha" {
  export interface Context {
    yourField: YourType;
  }
}
```